# To Do List with Unique value

Tags: javascript

I want vanilla javaScript for simple to do list which checks if the item already exist and adds a list item only if it doesn't exist.

I was able to add list items if were not unique. Even able to set an alert when item exist, but, it breaks at the point of creating a new item.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");


function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}


function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}


button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var listItems = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    if (listItems[i].innerText === input.value) {
      alert("Item already exist");
    } else if (inputLength() > 0) {
      createListElement();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="userinput" value="" />
<input id="enter" type="button" value="enter" />
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to outside of `for` loop  and chack is matched then save into variable to will `createListElement()` function will call or not

```
 else if (inputLength() > 0) {
          createListElement();
        }
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");


function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}


function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}


button.addEventListener("click", function() {
 
  var listItems = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
  let match =false;
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    if (listItems[i].innerText === input.value) {
      alert("Item already exist");
      matched =true;
    } 
  }
  if(matched ==false)
  {
    createListElement();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="userinput" value="" />
<input id="enter" type="button" value="enter" />
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) doesn't return an array, so you cannot use `for` on it. Use `forEach` instead.

Also you `if` statement was a bit weird, so i separated into a loop checking for values with the conditional insertion handled after the loop has ended:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");


function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}


function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}


button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var listItems = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
  var exists = false;
  listItems.forEach(function(listItem) {
    if (listItem.innerText === input.value) {
      exists = true;
      alert("Item already exist");
    }
  })
  if (!exists) {
    createListElement();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="userinput" value="" />
<input id="enter" type="button" value="enter" />
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Comment: I was able to use for loop to get this code working. Correct me, but I see querySelectorAll returning an array.

Comment: Good to hear. According to MDN, querySelectorAll [returns a static (not live) NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). This is somewhat similar to arrays as it has similar properties like `.length` and methods like `.forEach`.